# Help with flux double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a question regarding flux. 
The vector field $F(x,y,z) = 4xi + 4yj + 4zk$, and the surface $S$ is the sphere $x^2 +  y^2 + 4z^2 = 3$. Would it be best to attack this with through polar? How can I find the normal vector and $dS$ in the flux equation?

Comment: The equation $x^2 + y^2 + 4z^2 = 3$, in standard coordinates, represents an ellipsoid, not a sphere, so wassup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all $x^2 + y^2 + 4z^2 = 3$ isn't a sphere, but an ellipsoid. Yeah, it seems that you can do the problem using the polar coordinates, as the vector field is rather simple-looking. But you shouldn't use "pure" polar coordinates, in fact you should use elliptic coordinates, just because of the reason I mentioned above. If you're not familiar with the elliptic coordinates they are just the usual polar coordinates with some coordinates multiplied with various constants.

An easier way to solve this problem is by using the [Divergence (Gauss') Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) if you're familiar with it and you're allowed to use it. So we have:

$$\iint \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \ dS = \iiint \text{div}(\vec{F}) \ dV$$

where the first integral is over the boundary of the sphere, while the second over it's volume. As $\text{div}(\vec{F}) = 12$ this should make stuff simplier, basically reducing the problem to just finding the volume of the ellipsoid. You will again need to use elliptic coordinates to find it, but the calculations will be much easier.

Comment: Because the ellipsoid has a circular cross section, it's actually *very* easy to do the integral in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @eyeballfrog of course it's doable, but then the boundaries of z would be square roots, which isn't something I particularly like

Comment: Not if you integrate over $r$ first. You can use the $rdr$ in the Jacobian to change variables to $r^2$, making the square roots go away.

Comment: @eyeballfrog But we don't need the Jacobian, as we're doing a double integration. We need the normal vector wrt the coordinate change, i.r $N = \phi_r \times \phi_{\theta}$. The calculation gets a little bit nasty but eventually if I'm not mistake the integral would be $\iint \frac{-16r}{3\sqrt{4-r^2}} drd\theta$. It's not hard to evaluate this integral, but it's not like this way is much easier than mine.

Comment: I meant doing the volume integration in cylindrical, which I now see was unclear. I agree the surface integral in cylindrical would probably be horrendous.